# Copy a xml node to another node

Tags: php, xslt, xpath

I am a newbie to XML PHP and XPATH.

I have an XML file as follows

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sections>
 <section name="Windows 7" id="7">
   <section name="Registry" id="29">
    <section name="hkcu" id="30">
     <section name="software" id="31">
     </section>
    </section>
   </section>
 </section>
 <section name="Server 2012" id="33">
 </section>
</sections>
```

I can delete a node ie. `<section>` or add a `<section>`.
What I am struggling with is there a way to move a node and its children to another node IE section.
for example move the section with ID="30" and its children to say section with the ID="33".

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for XSLT here.

Comment: Oh god nothing simple is there!!

Comment: Anyone willing to give me a quick idea how to do this with XLST

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is designed to transform XML documents. It uses stylesheets describing the transformation from an input XML document to an output document.

E.g. the following transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- identity transformation -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- remove section with id 30 -->
  <xsl:template match="section[@id='30']"/>
  <!-- copy section with id 33 and add (as a child) section with id 30 -->
  <xsl:template match="section[@id='33']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="//section[@id='30']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will transform your input file into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sections>
  <section name="Windows 7" id="7">
    <section name="Registry" id="29">
    </section>
  </section>
  <section name="Server 2012" id="33">
    <section name="hkcu" id="30">
      <section name="software" id="31">
        </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</sections>
```

XPath and XSLT take a bit of learning to get started, but once you mastered it, you have a universal tool at hand for transforming XML documents any way you like.

Also, to run [XSLT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) in PHP (be sure to enable *extension=php_xsl.dll* or *extension=php_xsl.so* in .ini file) below will output a string XML value which can be dumped into a file or echoed to screen:

```php
// LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('XSLTSCript.xsl');

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

# ECHO OUTPUT STRING
echo $newXML;
```

Comment: Good answer. I edited to add the PHP code for OP to implement XSLT. Also, the double forward slashes except for last is redundant and I added output and strip tags in xslt. Edit as needed!

Comment: Thanks i will give that a try..Much appreciated,

Comment: @Parfait Thank your for the improvements to my answer.

Comment: Hi Guys One more question. What would be the best way to pass parameters to the XLST style sheet from PHP as I would like to do the above Dynamically. I have been reading up on it. Would I have to user XLST 2.0 or is there another way.

Comment: `<xsl:param>` and `XSLTProcessor::setParameter()` are the relevant keywords here. BTW, it's *XSLT*, not *XLST*.

Comment: Also @KevinWilson, you can embed the XSLT as a string in PHP and load with `loadXML()` and concatenate any string PHP variables as needed.